# Why tailwindcss doesnot import all the component correctly using sass files in webpack?

Tags: webpack, sass, tailwind-css

After learning tailwindcss, I want to give a try and test it in webpack. But webpack output file is small compare to the build file I was getting while building tailwindcss. Here is the details:
`colors.scss` file

```css
:root {
    --color-dark-1: #0D1117;
    --color-dark-2: #161B22;
}
```

`postcss.config.js` file

```js
module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        require('postcss-import'),
        require('tailwindcss'),
        require('autoprefixer')
    ]
  }
```

`tailwind.config.js` file

```js
module.exports = {
    mode: 'jit',
    purge: [],
    darkMode: false,
    theme: {
      extend: {
        colors:{
            black:{
                100: 'var(--color-dark-1)',
                200: 'var(--color-dark-2)'
            }
        }
      },
    },
    variants: {
        extends:{}
    },
    plugins: [],
  };
```

`app.scss` file

```css
@import './scss/colors';
@import "tailwindcss/base";
@import "tailwindcss/components";
@import "tailwindcss/utilities";
```

`webpack.config.js` file

```js
const { merge } = require('webpack-merge');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin')
const TerserWebpackPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const CssMinimizerPlugin = require('css-minimizer-webpack-plugin');
var common = {
    module : {
        rules : [
            {
                test: [/\.scss$/, /\.css$/],
                use: [
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    'css-loader',
                    'postcss-loader',
                    'sass-loader'
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: [/node_modules/],
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'babel-loader'
                    }
                ]
            },
            
        ]
    },
    optimization: {
        minimize: true,
        minimizer: [
            new TerserWebpackPlugin(),
            new CssMinimizerPlugin({})
        ]
    }
};
module.exports = [
    merge(common, {
        devtool: 'eval-source-map',
        entry: [
            __dirname + '/app/app.scss',
            __dirname + '/app/app.js'
        ],
        output: {
            path: __dirname + '/../public',
            filename: 'js/app.js',
        },
        resolve: {
            modules: [
                '/node_modules',
                __dirname + '/app'
            ]
        }
    })
];
```

The output file doesnot include all tailwindcss import files.
After generating `tailwind.config.js` using `npx tailwindcss init --full` command to generate the default configuation file, It works perfectly. I would like to know why in webpack it require to generate the default configuration file. Building with `postcss` work fine without generation the default `tailwind.config.js` file

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the trouble, I have to remove `mode: 'jit'` from `tailwind.config.js` file. [JTI](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/just-in-time-mode#enabling-jit-mode) feature is currently in preview